# default grid system in Bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

```
<div class="col-lg-1">hi</div>
<div class="col-lg-10">hi</div>
<div class="col-lg-1">hi</div>
```

v/s

```
<div class="col-xs-1">hi</div>
<div class="col-xs-10">hi</div>
<div class="col-xs-1">hi</div>
```

From what i'm seeing if you use .col-lg- to define the grid system in an app. For smaller screen sizes the app does not hold up. So much so, that even if you magnify the browser by ctrl +, the width becomes 100% of each .col-lg- div.

On the contrary if you use .col-xs- the behavior is as expected (great) on large screen sizes also. (so far as i've seen). Is there any drawback of using .col-xs- or .col-md- grid system for a web app? (even when it is intended for large screen sizes also)

[unexpected behavior](http://jsfiddle.net/sangramfuture/jC7af/2/) and  [expected behavior](http://jsfiddle.net/sangramfuture/jC7af/4/) just because the screen size of the fiddle is smaller than `.col-lg` can handle. So it makes each div 100% width

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The large grid  (with .col-lg) only becomes horizontal with a screensize of >=1200. The extra small grid (with .col-xs) always remain horizontal (and never stack).

> if you magnify the browser by ctrl +, the width becomes 100% of each
>   .col-lg- div.

True cause ctrl + doesn't change the screen size.

> Is there any drawback of using .col-xs- or .col-md- grid system for a
>   web app?

No. The col-xs will be the same for all screen sizes. In fact only using col-xs makes your app non-responsive. (When you use a navbar you will also set the @grid-breaking-point to 0).

In your case the medium grid .col-md will have the same "unexpected behavior" (unexpected for you) but for an screen size of >= 992 pixels.

Comment: Nope. When 2 col-6-* are shown next to each other (50% width) they are horizontal. When you make the screen smaller the col-6-* are shown under each other (100% width) which will be called stacked. So the xs-grid nevers stacks and always be horizontal (or unless you use a browser without css)

Comment: so please read your first line second sentence. i think it should be, will always remain horizontal instead of 'never become horizontal.